# Do not refresh (redirect) page after facebook login

Tags: python, django, facebook

I am using social_django library for facebook login. I am using the following function for the login process which is called on login button click. I've also set the redirect in settings.py pointing the the url namespace 'app'. The login works fine, except the fact that my app page gets refreshed and all the content in goes away. Is there an option to automatically close the facebook tab after login, and not refresh my app page?

I tried to open fb login in another tab, but still I will be redirected to my app page in that same tab.

```
function FBLogin(){
  window.open('{% url "social:begin" "facebook" %}');
}
```

in settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'app'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

window.open('{% url "social:begin" "facebook" %}', "_blank");

replace of

window.open('{% url "social:begin" "facebook" %}');